# Is there any way to track third party scripts loading additional scripts?

Tags: javascript

One of my websites is loading up a few more third party scripts than expected, and I'd like to know what is triggering those scripts to load. Is there any way to track the trigger/source for loading those additional scripts?

Comment: if this is in the browser press `F12` and in the Network tab there is a column called `Initiator`, that should tell you where and the position of the call.

Comment: I googled this question and didn't find an answer easily, so I think providing your comment as an answer would be good for others like me who don't know where to look.

Comment: @Abram you can just add an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I will certainly do so if @GetOffMyLawn doesn't care about being credited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By opening your browsers dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>, mac: <kbd>option+cmd+j</kbd>, windows: <kbd>ctrl+shift+j</kbd> in Chrome), you can open the `Network` tab and view the `Initiator` column which will display the file and location.

If you click on the link it will take you to the script. If the script is **minified**, you can expand it using the **pretty print** button `{}` which is in the bottom left corner.

[image]

So, if we click on say an **html** one, it will open a page that looks like this:

[image: Reference]

And a highlighted line will show where it is getting executed. In the above reference it is from a `script` tag.

Comment: Great, I'll mark this when it lets me. BTW, option+cmd+j also opens the console on mac.